# Add JPopup menu by right clicking on node in Swing in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtree, jpopupmenu

In GUI,I am displaying one `JTree` at the left hand side of `JPanel`. Now for each `Node(leaf)`, on Mouse right click I want to display `JPopup` menu asking for displaying the statistics about `Node` in right `JPanel`.

As i am new to swing,Could any one help with code.
Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Tushar Dodia.

Comment: I amend your post, please revert if isn't...

Answer (score 3):

Use JTree's method

```
public TreePath getPathForLocation(int x, int y)
```

Then TreePath

```
public Object getLastPathComponent()
```

That returns you desired node from point where user right clicked.

Comment: that's isn's about how to add MouseListener for JPopup to the JTree

Comment: I think the question is not "how to add popup" but "how to add popup depending on clicked node"

Comment: me too :) maybe you should mention the getTooltip(MouseEvent) as the place to configure the component popup depending on the node at that location

Answer (score 3):

Seem to have caused a bit of confusion (confusing myself ;-) - so here's a code snippet for doing target location related configuration of the componentPopup

```
    JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    final Action action = new AbstractAction("empty") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };
    popup.add(action); 
    JTree tree = new JTree() {

        /** 
         * @inherited <p>
         */
        @Override
        public Point getPopupLocation(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e != null) {
               TreePath path = getClosestPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
               action.putValue(Action.NAME, String.valueOf(path.getLastPathComponent()));
               return e.getPoint();
            }
            action.putValue(Action.NAME, "no mouse"); 
            return null;
        }

    };
    tree.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took @kleopatra solution and changed it slightly.
Maybe it isn't the best way but works for me.

```
JTree tree = new JTree() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override public Point getPopupLocation(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e == null) return new Point(0,0);
        TreePath path = getClosestPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        Object selected = path != null ? path.getLastPathComponent() : null;
        setComponentPopupMenu(getMenuForTreeNode(getComponentPopupMenu(), selected));
        setSelectionPath(path);
        return e.getPoint();
    }
};



public JPopupMenu getMenuForTreeNode(JPopupMenu menu, Object treeNode) {
    if (menu == null) menu = new JPopupMenu("Menu:");
    menu.removeAll();
    if (treeNode instanceof MyTreeItem) {
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("This is my tree item: " + treeNode.toString()));
    }
    return menu;
}
```

Comment: changing the componentPopup instance (not sure if you do it, just saying :-) would be a bit brittle: it depends on the calling code of getPopupLocation to call getComponentPopup _after_ requesting the location. Which is accidentally does in Oracle's BasicLookAndFeel, other implementations might not